# vb.net: word document iterating words very slow

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have the following code, which selects the text in the current page and then procedes to get each word (`wa` is the word application object):

```
    wa.Selection.MoveUp(Word.WdUnits.wdWindow, 1, 1) '0=move,1=extend
    wa.Selection.Collapse()
    wa.Selection.MoveDown(Word.WdUnits.wdWindow, 1, 1) '0=move,1=extend
    Dim r As Word.Range
    r = wa.Selection.FormattedText
    Dim Stopwatch As New Stopwatch()
    Stopwatch.Start()
    Dim params = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim wrd As String
    For i = 1 To r.Words.Count 'wa.Selection.Words.Count
       'params.Add(CStr(i), r.Words.Item(i).Text)
        wrd = r.Words.Item(i).Text 'wa.Selection.Words.Item(i).Text.ToString()
    Next
    Stopwatch.Stop()
    MsgBox(Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds & "###" & wa.Selection.Words.Count)
```

In the above section, i get all the text of the current page and want to get each word's text.
the current page where i test is 450 words. it takes 3200 milliseconds, which is way too much, about 7ms per word. if i limit it to 100 words, it's 160 milliseconds, about 1.6/ms per word. If i limit to 50 words, it's 45 milliseconds, less than one ms per word.

Initially I was trying to get it from the `Selection` object, but the speed is the same.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I improve on this?

Looping through an array of 450 items and just doing an assignment shouldn't take 3.2 seconds.

Comment: Try parsing the range based on paragraphs and then words within each paragraph. A paragraph mark counts as a word range and thus if your 450 word range contained 200 short paragraphs, your current code would be looking at 200 items it doesn’t need. That should save a little time, though maybe not enough ...

Comment: @RichMichaels there are only 5 paragraphs in the page. but still, doesn't seem normal to me that looping through 450 items in a collection should take over three seconds

Comment: I agree with you, it shouldn’t take 3 seconds. I was only trying to eliminate possibilities of WHY? For another test you might try running the code in a VBA routine. This would take VS out of the equation.

Comment: I tried a For Each and got a very tiny improvement. Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/about-the-open-xml-sdk?redirectedfrom=MSDN and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/getting-started?redirectedfrom=MSDN might be worth a look.

Comment: why you need to loop for each word in selection ? maybe try to get all selection text and then split it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looping through an array of 450 items and just doing an assignment shouldn't take 3.2 seconds.

You are iterating through a `Words` collection not an array.  If I recall correctly, these collections get populated/evaluated on each access of their items.

An alternative would be use a Word.Range object and move its Start and End points to the next word.  The following is one such implementation of this technique.

```
Dim params As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim count As Int32 = 0

Dim currentPageRange As Word.Range = wa.Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
Dim currentWordRange As Word.Range = doc.Range((currentPageRange.Start), (currentPageRange.Start))

Dim endOfRange As Int32 = currentPageRange.End ' store this position locally to avoid the interop property get on each iteration of the while loop

While currentWordRange.Start < endOfRange
  count += 1
  currentWordRange.Expand(Word.WdUnits.wdWord) ' move end to start of next word
  params.Add(count.ToString(), currentWordRange.Text)
  currentWordRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd) ' collapse to start of next word
End While
```

Running this code against a page with 655 words takes about 600 ms while iterating the `Words` collection takes about 3100 ms.